# How to use HttpHeaders Link for pagination in Angular project?

Tags: angular, rest, github

The  response from api.github  has a response header with Link.

How should I use it?
it return a string like this

`<https://api.github.com/user/repos?per_page=10&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/user/repos?per_page=10&page=4>; rel="last"`

it need to parse by myselef?

[image: HttpHeaders.Link]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to parse it yourself. Here's how to do it with `split`, `reduce`, and a regular expression.

```js
let linkHeaders = '<https://api.github.com/user/repos?per_page=10&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/user/repos?per_page=10&page=4>; rel="last"'

let parts = linkHeaders.split(',').reduce((acc, link) => {
   let match = link.match(/<(.*)>; rel="(\w*)"/)
   let url = match[1]
   let rel = match[2]
   acc[rel] = url
   return acc;
}, {})

console.log(parts)
```

Comment: Ok , thank you . Maybe  the link return jsonString like {total:number,current:number}  better than this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Retrun a string which can be parsed by JSON.parse()?

Comment: Yea, most APIs tend to put pagination data in the JSON response. I don't know why they used headers. example: http://jsonapi.org/examples/#pagination

Comment: restfull standard seem to prefer return the resource data direct in the body, other info like pagination passed by header.